# Distribution of a quadratic form

Tags: matrices, probability-distributions, quadratic-forms

Let $A$ be a symmetric positive definite matrix, and $x$ a random vector. Suppose we know the distribution of $x^\top A x$. What can we say about the distribution of $x^\top x$?